# Static Variables somehow maintaining state?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an existing project, setup by another coder. I'm having some trouble understanding how state is being maintained between pages. There is a Class library which has some helper objects. Mostly these objects are just used for there static methods and rarely instantiated or inherited.

This is an example class I'm testing with.

```
public sealed class Application
{
    public static string Test;
}
```

Now when i run something like the following in the base class of my page, I would expect the result to be "1: 2:Test" all the time (note that "1" is empty), but strangly its only this way the first time it is run. Then every time afterwards its "1:Test 2:Test". Somehow its maintaining the state of the static variable between pages and being refreshed??

```
Response.Write("1:" + SharedLibrary.Application.Test);

SharedLibrary.Application.Test = "Test";

Response.Write(" 2:" + SharedLibrary.Application.Test);
```

I need to create more classes like this, but want to understand why this is occurring in the first place.

Many Thanks

Comment: By "pages and being refreshed" does that mean that you use this Class library in ASP.Net or what?

Comment: This is correct, its an ASP.Net App

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As correctly stated by others: Anything declared as static variable in an Asp.Net application will keep its same value until changed.

Here is what you really need to know:

- This value will be lost when (not *if*, but *when*) the application pool recycles. Usually this happens daily, but also happens if you run out of memory or otherwise crash.
- This value will be accessed by all the requests concurrently, i.e. multiple users, etc.

So if this value is a counter for example:

```
Response.Write("1:" + SharedLibrary.Application.Test);
SharedLibrary.Application.Test = int.Parse(SharedLibrary.Application.Test) + 1;
Response.Write(" 2:" + SharedLibrary.Application.Test);
```

You might find unexpected output such as "1: 53 2: 55". This would be a result of executing your test page at the same time from a couple of browsers.

- Static variables always initialize when you first access or create an instance of the class. They all initialize. So if you have a large "bucket" o' static variables (I call badly designed helper classes "buckets"), and you only use one of them, the memory for each one is still allocated at that time.
- Finally, this value is *never* garbage collected. So if you put a large item in the static variable, then it will consume that memory as long as the process lives. (Please do not put Disposable resources, i.e. SqlConnection's, in there.)

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.Net, static variable keep their state as long as the server is running (with a few exceptions). If you want to have a static variable that doesn't keep it's state across page refreshes(read: HTTP requests) then wrap a property around the `HttpContext` class.

Answer (score 0):

Most web applications/frameworks actually keep the code running between invocations, and only stop it when the server or worker is shut down. PHP is the odd one out here, not everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

A *static class* or *static member* once loaded (accessed) *remains in memory* until the application that loaded it, is *unloaded*.  So, when your page requests access the static member *`SharedLibrary.Application.Test`* each request is accessing the same memory location.

The MSDN article [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)  will give you some additional insight.

When you say you need to create more class like this, what is it that you want these classes to do?

Comment: Basically just global variable classes, they will all exist as static variables in different classes since we have several types of global variables. Some are brought from the database, some are constants and some are calculated based in the client.

Comment: Use them cautiously, statics provide predictable behavior but can be quite unexpected if not well thought out. Calculated based on the client -- This sounds betters suited to a session variable. Database -- Do you really need to reduce to the connections? You might get better optimization using caching. constants -- Ok, I'll give you constants.